# How to find E[X] of joint probability distribution?

Tags: probability

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ have the following joint probability density function:

$$f(x,y)=\frac{3}{1004}y$$

$$0 < x <9, y > 0 , x-4 < y < x + 4$$

Find $E[X]$

By definition of $E[X]$ of joint probability distribution:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(f(x,y))dxdy$$

But, in this case we would then have:

$$\int_{x-4}^{x+4}\int_{0}^{9} x(\frac{3}{1004}y)dxdy$$

Which makes no sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: Do the $y$ integral first.  And BTW the lower limit must satisfy _both_ $y > x-4$ and $y > 0$.

Comment: @antkam Ok thank you. So what would the lower limit be then to satisfy y > x - 4 and y > 0? And also I thought order of integration matters? How can you just change the order from dxdy to dydx?

Comment: (1) If you need to satisfy both $y > a$ and $y > b$... hint: would it be $y > min(a,b)$ or $y > max(a,b)$?  (2) the order of integration matter sometimes, but in this case, you're really integrating over an area in the $(x,y)$-plane bounded by five lines: $x >0, x < 9, y >0, y < x-4, y < x+4$.  I'm pretty sure it's a $5$-sided irregular polygon.  You can integrate either direction first, as long as you get your limits correct.  Given the form of the boundaries/constraints, I thought integrating $y$ first might be easier.  But honestly, you should start by drawing the $5$-sided polygon.